# magento 2 email issue variable not working {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}

Tags: magento2

All order emails sends in this way without getting customer name or any details should getting from email variable.

```
Hi, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

Also Payment method section its displayed as html

```
 <dl class="payment-method"> <dt class="title"> Cash On Delivery</dt> </dl>
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Refer `magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\email\order_new.html`

Answer (score 3):

In 2.3.5 it seems that this is the correct way to add the name to transactional emails (at least new order email):

```
{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

for New Order/Invoice Email template(Customer)

```
{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

For New Order/Invoice Email template(Guest)

```
{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea that how to get Guest customer name in credit/shipment email templates?

Answer (score 0):

I appear to be getting the exact same problem with the order template and the same problem with other templates not populating with data.. i.e new password field is empty. Any links generated are invalid and met with 404 pages.
It seems that all templates are affected in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating from Magento 1. The solution is to install a fresh Magento 2 and copy the E-Mail template from there or copy the parts you need.